# How to check if url has certain part in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Like the title says, I want to know how to check if url has certain part of it, for example if the url is: `testurl.com/id`, how to check if `id` is present in the url? Now, why I want to know this, is because I am trying to check if id is present in my component, here is my code:

```
const User = (props) => {


const { name, email, status, gender, title, method } = props.location.user;

  const { id } = useParams();

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState(name);
  const [newEmail, setNewEmail] = useState(email);
  const [newStatus, setNewStatus] = useState(status);
  const [newGender, setNewGender] = useState(gender);

  const updateName = (e) => {
    setNewName(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateEmail = (e) => {
    setNewEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateStatus = (e) => {
    setNewStatus(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateGender = (e) => {
    setNewGender(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateData = () => {
    if (method === "put") {
      axios
        .put(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users/${id}`,
          {
            name: newName,
            email: newEmail,
            status: newStatus,
            gender: newGender,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response.status === 422) {
            alert(
              "Error: The format of email is wrong! Please put it like this: yourname@yourname.com"
            );
          }
        });
    } else if (method === "post") {
      axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users/`,
          {
            name: newName,
            email: newEmail,
            status: newStatus,
            gender: newGender,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response.status === 422) {
            alert("Error: Name or email already taken!");
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

As you can see, in this component I have a function: `const updateData = ()=>...` and inside the function I am checking if the method is put do this, and if the method is post do that. How do I check if the id is present in the url then do the put method, and if it isn't then do the post method. So i can then check the method without using props that are passed using Link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using react-router. You can define a parameter in your route:

```
<Route path="/:id" component={...} />
```

Then, you can use `useParams` hook to check that parameter, as you've already done in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Params get passed down through props on the match object.

> props.match.params.yourParams

Reference: https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router

Example:

```
if (props.match.params.id) method = "put" else method = "post"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only change the target url in the `axios` request you could use the default function of `axios`

```
axios({
    method: !!id ? 'put' : 'post',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}users/${!!id ? id : ''}`,
    data: {
        name: newName,
        email: newEmail,
        status: newStatus,
        gender: newGender,
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
})
```

The `!!` operator checks for truthy values which in case of a string means if it has any value besides an empty string.